# What are the requirements for IssuerScripts

Tags: smartcard, apdu, emv

I am totally stumped about Issuer Scripts in EMV.  I know what they are and I have read the EMV book 3.   I was wondering if anyone has a good summary that tells me:

1. Parse the script based on "86".
2. Then based upon some  values do this or that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content of EMV TAG 0x86 is ready to use [APDU command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card_application_protocol_data_unit) for the smartcard. It could be any of EMV or ISO 7816 Commands actually and should be translated to smartcard thru EMV terminal application/kernel without additional modifications.

Here are usual APDU *Instructions* (INS) for Issuer scripts:

```
- 16: EMV, Card Block
- 18: EMV, Application Unblock
- 1E: EMV, Application Block
- 24: EMV, Pin Change/Unblock
- DC: ISO 7816-4, Update Record
```

Please keep in mind that Message Authentication Code (MAC) data component used in the APDU Command to protect(sign) the command body.

The Commands descriptions you can find in EMV Book 3 and in the ISO 7816-4.